# TFS won't receive request from external URL

Tags: version-control, tfs

My TFS is working fine for: `http://localhost:8081` (notification URL).
But my other domain: www.sub.mysite.com (example), which succesfully resolves to other sites inside my IIS, will simply not load up TFS. Basically it sits on "connecting" then eventually times out.

What I don't understand is, when I change the URL in the TFS Admin console, I've noticed it doesn't even update the IIS bindings.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

This could be the the old [double-hop](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/06/13/understanding-kerberos-double-hop.aspx) issue?  But I can't really tell as the question isn't specific.

Comment: My apologies it was my Amazon ec2 instance needed to open port in AWS :/